# Issues installing NeuralProphet in .conda env - error building wheel

Tags: python, python-wheel, reticulate

I am new to python, but I am trying to install neural prophet to use through reticulate in R, and I'm having issues getting it installed.

I tried doing pip install of neural prophet, and it will not work although all the other packages are installed.

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [20 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rachelalaynahall/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "/Users/rachelalaynahall/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/rachelalaynahall/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/gf/8cmvg9v136b24g9zcn9289pc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-57ppifq1/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/gf/8cmvg9v136b24g9zcn9289pc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-57ppifq1/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "/private/var/folders/gf/8cmvg9v136b24g9zcn9289pc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-57ppifq1/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "/private/var/folders/gf/8cmvg9v136b24g9zcn9289pc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-57ppifq1/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 18, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

(base) rachelalaynahall@Joshuas-Air climate %